# Utility class instead of superclass getter

Tags: java, module

I have following package structure:

- a (contains A.java, AUtils.java) - non-exported package
- b (contains B.java, which is A subclass) - exported package
- c (contains C.java, which is A subclass, but uses B and its info) - exported package

Class A contains a package-private field getter `getInfo()`. I don't want to have it exposed out of my module. Classes B and C need to access `getInfo()`, so I created AUtils.java utility class, which basically allow all of my classes to access the getter via method `AUtils.getInfo(A aInstance)`.

Is this considered as a bad practice? Is there any simpler way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "`protected`" modifier for `getInfo()` method

Comment: I forgot to mention that C class uses B class, so B.getInfo() can't be accessed inside C